# Can melacha be done to hear the Hakhel on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, halacha-theory, melacha-creative-work, hakhel

According to Halacha, types  of melacha which were necessary for the temple were permitted to be performed on Shabbat for the purpose of the Korban sacrifice and the temple operations. My question is, when the Mitvzah of Hakhel is in effect, can melachot be performed to hear the Hakhel reading from the king?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Haqhel day was to fall on Shabbat it was pushed off to the next day since the extra things involved do not override Shabbat (Rambam Chagiga 3:7).